# Why am I getting assembly version as 0.0.0.0? Will that make any issues if real DLL has some version number and using Type class to retrieve values?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005

I have a project named "Test.LiveModel" (`Test.LiveModel.dll`) and its version is 8.0.7.0 in my solution which contains 25 projects.  I can see the information of `Test.LiveModel` in `AssemblyInfo.cs`.  I have two category of objects named 'base class category' and 'user-defined class category' which are displaying in my application UI. I am displaying this through a property  which is of class `Type`

Now I am considering one base class category object named "Server" and one user-defined class category object `RoundedTree`.  When I set value as "Server" in Property in Grid after saving it when I restart my application I can see the saved value, but for "RoundedTree" which is not happening due to type becomes null.  So I did a thorough analysis and came to know that issue is in `ToType()` method shown below 
This is `ToType()` metho

For base class `Server` `xmlSerializableType.Name`, I am getting as `Test.LiveModel.Server` and `AssemblyName` I am getting as `Test.LiveModel, Version=8.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23bd062a94e26d58` and `type` I am getting by using `Type.GetType` as `type = {Name = "Server" FullName = "Test.LiveModel.Server"}`

But for user defined class `xmlSerializableType.Name` I am getting as `_Rounded_Tree`.  'type' I am getting as `null` by using `Type.GetType`.  `AssemblyName` I am getting as `_Rounded_TreeTest-Machine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`, but even `assembly.GetType` I am getting as null.  What is the reason behind it?  Why am I getting assembly version 0.0.0.0?  I mean full assembly `_Rounded_TreeTest-Machine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.

This is the method `CreateType()` which will create assembly and type as `myTypeBuilder` for userdefined class:

```
 public Type CreateType()
  {

     // Create the assembly name by appending the machine name to the typename.
     myAsmName.Name = this.TypeName + Environment.MachineName;
     // Define assembly that can be executed but not saved
     this.UserClassAssemblyBuilder = myDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(myAsmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
     // Create dynamic module with symbol information
     this.UserClassModuleBuilder = this.UserClassAssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("userdefinedmodule", true);
```

So here is my question: if real Dll has some version number, and user defined class assembly has version 0.0.0.0, is that the reason why I am getting type as null after using `Type.GetType` and `assembly.GetType` method?

Comment: I tried to clean the question up, but too much of it I simply didn't understand what you were saying.  It's really hard to read.

Comment: @Inuyasha My question simply is why i am getting null for catogory "userdefinedclass" by using Type.GetType and even used assembly.GetType though everything is created in Type CreateType() method

Comment: You can add a assembly version when creating the dynamic module, maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions which may solve the problems.

#### Define a assembly version

```
new AssemblyName(this.TypeName + Environment.MachineName) 
{ 
    Version = new Version("1.0.0.0") 
};
```

#### Use full qualified names for the serialization

```
myObject.GetType().FullName
```

Comment: So you mean instead of using          //AssemblyName myAsmName = new AssemblyName();

         //// Create the assembly name by appending the machine name to the typename.
         //myAsmName.Name = this.TypeName + Environment.MachineName;  replace as AssemblyName myAsmName = new AssemblyName(this.TypeName + Environment.MachineName);
         { Version = new Version("1.0.0.0"); }  but its throwing errors like "Error 5 'System.Version' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'"

Comment: but its throwing errors like "Error 5 'System.Version' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'"

Comment: You need to remove the `;` behind `new AssemblyName(this.TypeName + Environment.MachineName)` then it should work.
If it does not your .NET Version does not support it. then you should use: `AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName(...); asmName.Version = new Version(...)`.